# Perl console window - how to make it non-closable?

Tags: windows, perl, windows-console

I'd like to know if there's any way to hide the closing button or at least make it non-clickable when using Perl in console. I know it's possible when using GUI, but I need to make a console-based application and don't want the user to close it on purpose.

Comment: Any process can be closed, so what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What do you mean by "Perl in console"? Console? Is that a terminal window? Which OS? Which terminal?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve that you will need to write a command to close it.
Perl in console is meant to be MS Windows' Terminal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
use strict;
use Win32::Console::ANSI qw/ SetCloseButton /;

$SIG{INT}='IGNORE';   # no Ctrl-C interrupt
SetCloseButton(0);    # no close button
```

Comment: This is clever. Do you know if it also traps the Alt+F4 keyboard shortcut?

Comment: This is a great solution, thanks. I don't mind the Alt + F4 combination to close the window, this is just enough for me.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can prevent users from closing the Windows command prompt window. Not only would you have to hide the close button, but you'd have to hide the associated system menu items, context menu items (depending on the flavor of Windows), and capture the `Alt + F4` keyboard shortcut.

If you had control over the entire end-to-end process, you *could* do something clever by making the console window hidden, capturing the output, and sending it to a window you created (without the close capability, of course).

Otherwise, you're just going to have to trust that your users are big boys and girls and won't close the window.